# youtube api from display name get username

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have display name from youtube. How do i get username?

My code as below :-

```
 public static YouTubeVideoObject[] GetVideos(string User)
   {

           YouTubeRequestSettings settings =
           new YouTubeRequestSettings(User, YOUTUBE_DEVELOPER_KEY);
           YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
           User = User.Replace(" ", "%20");
           string feedUrl = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=" + User + "&orderby=published";

           Feed<Video> videoFeed = request.Get<Video>(new Uri(feedUrl));
           return (from video in videoFeed.Entries
                   select new YouTubeVideoObject() { VideoId = video.VideoId, Title = video.Title, Description = video.Description }).ToArray();

   }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: What if multiple users have the same display name ?

Comment: @Alex display all related video